# which Payment gateway is supported by Google App Engine (java) without redirecting to their native website

Tags: java, google-app-engine, paypal, payment-gateway, website-payment-pro

i am looking for a payment gateway which is compatible with GAE(google app engine **java**).

My requirement restrict me to use that payment gateway which support "**DoDirect payment**" (do not redirect users to their native website for transaction) like Google checkout or PayPal pro...

i have also searched Authorized.netas well but no luck. i came up with only one option that is 
"**PayPal adaptive API**" or "**Paypal X**" ,this is not an ideal approach but some how it cater my requirement.

Before i start implementing this i want to have a an idea that am i going in the right direction or did i miss any payment gateway.

Please help!!

---

Actually i want customers to pay for once in a life time to use my website by registering at my sign up page so that Next time when a paid customer enters the website , he/she will be asked to enter their login credentials to use it without paying again.

now if i use paypal buy now button, does it allow me to have a parameter (for my internal coding ) which checks whether the transaction is successful or not?   and redirects it to my mentioned page?

Comment: I know it might not be relevant, but I'm just wondering- what is forcing you to avoid redirection-based services?

Comment: client's requirement....

Comment: Adaptive Payments still requires a redirect. Website Payments Pro (or Website Payments Pro Hosted) are the only PayPal offerings that don't require a redirect. But there's no GAE code/SDK available as far as I know.

Comment: Adaptive Payments will show you a popup window (= new browser window), if user isn't yet logged in Paypal. Or, if user wants to make some extra stuff, like adding new shipping address, add new credit card, etc. Embedded frame works only for very simple payments

Comment: @splix You mean "Embedded Payments". Adaptive Payments does not determine your interface for you.

Comment: @nida With Embedded Payments you can embed the PayPal interface into your site using an iframe (really finicky in my experience) or a mini-browser popup. As splix mentioned even if you use the iframe method the mini-browser is necessary for many operations.

Answer (score 1):

We're recent converts to Stripe.com and so far the integration has been *really* easy. Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated w/ Stripe, and I haven't put it in production yet.  Ask them for some clients to check references.

Tangentially, Dwolla has a nice API.  They don't process credit cards, but facilitate direct bank-to-bank transfers, and they charge way, way, *way* less than credit card processors.  I think transactions under $10 are FREE right now, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by passing an encrypted parameter to the return url

```
<input name="CANCELURL" value='errorurl' type="hidden"/>
<input name="return" value='returnurl' type="hidden"/>
```

These are the return and cancel url parameters. You can append the return value as a query string with the 'returnurl'

---

If you do not want to redirect to paypal and payment should be done in the page you provided, you can use [paypal express check out](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code). This method will not redirect the page to paypal.

Comment: but what about transaction id ?
n do u mean there will be no return URL if the transaction is failed ?

Comment: If the transaction is successful you can set a status according to the return url